# Icon is coming only in Windows Phone browser

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing a web app, in the page developed i am seeing this weird icon at the bottom of the page after the footer [image]

It is not coming in other android or iOS.

Please help in solving why this image is coming only in windows phone browser.

Comment: What language? Is it really happening in both wp7 and wp8? Where is your code? What is the image type? Are you using something like phonegap?

Comment: @AMR: Thanks For the help. My issue is solved that image which is not loaded is shown as like that icon in WP browsers, but all the other browsers is neglecting the image tag with no image loaded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My issue is solved that image which is not loaded in the page is shown as like that icon in WP browsers, but all the other browsers is neglecting the image tag with no image loaded.